# the two div under wrapper follows the wrapper div's margin-top value, it should not

Tags: html, css

So i'm coding my website now, and i'm using two div to create a somewhat gradient in the background, where div#bg1 is grey and div#bg2 is dark grey. But when i'm then adding the wrapper div, bg1 and bg2 still follows the wrapper's top alignement, but it should not. bg1 and bg2 should stay at the top.

**heres the html:**

```
<div id="bg1"> </div>
<div id="bg2"> </div>
    <div id="wrapper"></div>
```

**and stylesheet:**

```
div#wrapper {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 800px;
  height: 1000px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:3;
}

div#bg1 {
  width: 100%;
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 60px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

div#bg2 {
  width: 100%;
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #444444;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 60px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

i have the code currently on my website here: http://andreassvarholt.com/test/test3/

Comment: try to add "top:0;" in div#bg2 and div#bg1

Answer (score 0):

You have both your BG divs set to an absolute position.

To force them to the top, you need to define the "top" CSS attribute.

```
  div#bg1 {
    top: 0;
  }

  div#bg2 {
    top: 0;
  }
```

Furthermore, I must point out that your implementation is inelegant.  Just make a 1px by 200px image that tiles as a background image on the body.  There's no sense in stacking divs on top of divs just for a simple background effect.

Answer (score 0):

Using divs to creat a background gradient is kind of jenky. Why not just go to one of the many free css3 gradient generators available online. Free and easy.

Good Luck
-brian